# Notice: Undefined index $_POST and mysql

Tags: php

If I set

```
$USER = (isset($_POST['username']));
```

with php have 0 errors **BUT** in db put '1' instead the it to user write on HTML input and if I put

```
`$USER = $_POST['username'];`

Notice: Undefined index: username in __FILE__ on line 5
```

this set in the db what user put in the HTML input, but get error

(Sorry for my bad English; I know it is so bad!)

Comment: `$USER = (isset($_POST['username']));` You return true or false in the variable `$USER`. That's why you get 1 or 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below :-

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $USER = $_POST['username']);
}
```

As, `isset()` is a function which gives return values in boolean i.e; 1 or 0

Comment: Thank you for editing the code. I will  take care from now regarding changes :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this :

```
$USER = (isset($_POST['username']));
```

You check if `$_POST['username']` is set AND you set this result (true or false) into `$USER`

What you want to do is :

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) // You check if username is set.
{
     $USER = $_POST['username'];
     // your query
}
else
{
    // return error if isn't set.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `isset()` is a checking operand type and returns 1 if true and 0 if false depending on something exist or not. I guess you got why this always output and saved 1 in the db.

So it should be `$USER = $_POST['username'];`

But the reason why you are getting `Notice: Undefined index: username in __FILE__ on line 5` because when you first enter that page, it dont post anything. So as a matter of fact `$_POST['username']` is unknown to php at that time. When you are submitting the form then php will know and recognize  `$_POST['username']`.

So you need to put a check like below:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  echo $_POST['username'];
}
```

Hope it will work and make you understand the problem.

Regards.